# GDI+ Graphics.DrawString with TextTrimming set to EllipsisCharacter doesn't work if output rectangle contains one character

Tags: winforms, gdi+, ellipsis, drawstring, texttrimming

We use the classic GDI+ [DrawString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21kdfbzs(v=vs.110).aspx) method to output text and set the Trimming property of its *format* parameter to EllipsisCharacter (see also the [StringTrimming enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringtrimming(v=vs.110).aspx)). If the output rectangle is enough small so it can display just one character, the ellipsis is not present on the screen - which misleads the user:

[image]

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, of course, make the column wider.  The ellipsis is a character too, it needs space.  This comment has a remarkably high doh factor :)

Comment: @HansPassant, is there a way to cause DrawString to draw ellipsis instead of one character in this case? Something like Excel displays '##' if the cell width isn't enough. This is our goal.

Comment: As I said, ellipsis is a character too, "\u2026", of course you can draw it yourself.